# How can I find values which does not contains characters and spaces?

Tags: regex

Below is sample data from the list I am working with:

```
74
7491
75
75010
75013
78
8081
84
8400 Winterthu
852
9000 Aalborg
974
A
A CORU√ëA
aa
Aalborg
Aargau
Aarhus
aas
AAT
AB
ABERC
Abu Dhabi
Abuja
AC
ACT
AD
```

Using `[^\p{L}-]` I can get a list but it also includes the following values which I do not want in the list

```
Abu Dhabi
Puerto Rico
Hong Kong
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It seems you need `^[^\p{L}-]+$` - strings that do not contain letters and hyphens.

Comment: Please let know if it works, else explain the rules.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find **multiple** items, so you must use `g` option.

You will be checking **each line** separately. Usual way the pattern
for such case is constructed is `^...$`, but both  `^` and `$`
should match begin and end of **each line**, not the whole string.
So you must use `m` option.

And the last point, what should be the accepted content of a candidate
line, i.e. what should be between `^` and `$`: Any not empty sequence of
letters in any language or literal minus, i.e. `[\p{L}-]+`.

So, to sum up, the whole regex should be:

```
/^[\p{L}-]+$/gm
```

This way names containing a space (e.g. *Puerto Rico*) will not be matched
(as you specified).

Answer (score 0):

Say your file is `test.dat`

A 1 simple line in `grep` will give wat you want:

```
grep -o -P  "[0-9]+$" test.dat
```

Output:

```
74
7491
75
75010
75013
78
8081
84
852
974
```